# What will be the value of 'this' for a function in an array in an object?

Tags: javascript, this

What will be the value of `this` for the function in the `methodArray` array, which is a property of `myObject`? Also, is `methodArray[0]` a normal function or a method?

```js
let myObject = {
  property: "Prakhar",
  methodArray: [
    function () {
      console.log(this);
    },
  ],
};

myObject.methodArray[0]();
```

On executing this code in browser, it is printing the array. Not sure why it is? Ideally it should be the window object (global) if the function is not a method or `myObject` if the function is a method.

Comment: When I run the code, I get an array containing a function.

Comment: Note that a function is not intrinsically a method; it totally depends on how the function is called. Functions do not have permanent relationships to objects unless that's explicitly done by binding.

Comment: it's `myObject.methodArray` apparently

Comment: Equivalent to: `myObject["methodArray"][0]()` in case you were expecting the `.` to be somehow relevant to how `this` is defined.

Comment: `methodArray[0]` is a function and not a method. It is a method when it is called as part of an object, but when it is accessed directly like in this case, it is just a plain function.

Comment: @AfzalK. Why is it not a method? It is being called as a property (`'0'`) of the `methodArray` array object.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/15261914

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What will be the value of `this` inside `methodArray` function?

It depends on how the function is invoked.

For an in-depth overview of `this`, see [MDN > `this` > Function context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context). Here's a quoted snippet that applies to the code in your example:

> For a typical function, the value of `this` is the object that the function is accessed on. In other words, if the function call is in the form `obj.f()`, then `this` refers to `obj`.

In your example…

> ```js
> myObject.methodArray[0]();
> ```

…the function is invoked as a method at the property `0` of the array `methodArray` (keep in mind that [arrays are objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and property `0` is being accessed using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)), so the value of `this` will be the array.

To illustrate further, here is a slightly modified version of your example code which returns the inner `this` value of the function so that it can be used for comparison outside the function:

```js
let myObject = {
  property: "Prakhar",
  methodArray: [
    function () {
      return this;
    },
  ],
};

const thisResult = myObject.methodArray[0]();

console.log(thisResult === myObject.methodArray); // true
```

---

> Also is `methodArray[0]` a function or method?

A [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Method) is a function which is a property of an object. So the function at property `0` of the array object is a method.

Comment: Would be great if you mentioned using `bind()` to control `this`. And the difference with arrow functions (`this` based on declaration site instead of call site). :)

Comment: arrow functions don't have their own `this` binding, so we can't use `bind()` to change it?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77338416/what-will-be-the-value-of-this-in-following-javascript-code-block/77338478#comment136342365_77338478) @DarrylNoakes Thanks for the feedback. I wanted to keep the answer focused on the question(s) asked because the topic of the `this` keyword is already abstract and has been extensively covered on this site. I searched for duplicates before answering and was surprised that I didn't find a duplicate target for this one. The links to the MDN articles cover everything in great detail (greater than appropriate for a single answer here).

Comment: Thanks @jsejcksn for your detailed explanation. I tried asking this to Chatgpt and it was giving the wrong answer. Interesting that functions inside arrays are also methods because arrays are eventually objects.

Comment: @jsejcksn Sure, understood